# Java & Hibernate - PersistEventListener does not set value properly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue with Hibernate:

I have a basic DAO that saves an entity the following way:

```
@Override
public void save(BaseEntity entity) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
    session.persist(entity);
    trans.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

I've registered a basic event listener for persisting the entity:

```
@Component
public class OwlPreSaveListener implements PersistEventListener {

     @Override
     public void onPersist(PersistEvent persistEvent) throws HibernateException {
        Object o = persistEvent.getObject();

        if (o instanceof BaseEntity) {
            BaseEntity entity = (BaseEntity)o;
            if (entity.getCreated() == null) {
                entity.setCreated(new Date());
            }
            entity.setUpdated(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to persist an entity I do NOT set a create date though it is mandatory because I assume that the listener will properly set it before persist. When running in debug mode the EventListener is triggered as expected. And when examining the entity the values are properly set.

There are actually logs indicating that the right values are associated with my entity:

```
23:49:40.545 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
23:49:40.545 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
23:49:40.546 [main] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
23:49:40.546 [main] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - com.owl.core.model.User{id=89672b6e-4f8e-4bfc-b24c-3cb3f853cad9, email=v9i0t0sg@dgs88uab.6p8, updated=Fri Oct 24 23:49:40 CEST 2014, created=Fri Oct 24 23:49:40 CEST 2014, name=9v9nduqfpsmn0 fjpufh2c713q2, deleted=null}
```

Note that the 'CREATED' date is **NOT** empty.

Regardless I get the following message time and time again:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'created' cannot be null

Spring : 4.1.1.RELEASE
Hibernate: 4.3.5.Final
```

I've tried saveOrUpdate event listener as well with no luck.

It is almost like setting a different value inside the event listener has no effect when actually persisting the entity.

Not quite sure what is goind on can anybody please suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

Please try `@DynamicInsert` and see if error dissapear. Maybe examine you table schema for specially CREATED column set default value for it and see what happens.